# How should I waterproof/seal a large hole in my basement wall?

Tags: basement, waterproofing, cement

There is a small 8"x12" plexiglass window in my basement that I want to seal/waterproof and then cover with soil. On the exterior of the house the window is at the base of a negative slope in the yard, that could easily be fixed by just getting rid of the "window" and adding a few inches of soil. 
The foundation continues a good foot in a half over the window, before you hit shingles, so there's no issue there. What I'm wondering is what is the best way to seal this weird window?

Comment: Concrete wall? Is the space habitable? Code requires a window that can be used for a fire escape

Comment: It's a concrete wall, basement is not habitable, window wouldn't be to code for fire escape if it was functional.